# Getting java.net.ConnectException while connecting Elasticsearch from Java

Tags: java, ssl, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, elastic-stack

I am using following code to connect Elasticsearch from java using jks and basic authentication. But I am getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem at the end while doing search.

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(esConfig.getEsUserName(), esConfig.getEsPassword()));

            InputStream actualPath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(esConfig.getJksFileName());

KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
truststore.load(actualPath, esConfig.getKeystorePassword().toCharArray() );

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(truststore, null)
                    .build();
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(esConfig.getEsHost()[0], esConfig.getEsPort(), "https"))
                    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                            return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).setSSLContext(sslContext);

                        }
                    });

client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
```

This is the code to create client and i did not see any exception there but when using following code to perform search I am getting this error.

```
searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
```

Any help is appreciated. JKS pasword is correct as able to open the jks file with that password